# show overlayer on click on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that on click needs to trigger an overlayer to bring the focus on the dropdown menu.
I have 2 dropdown menus, for this reason i can't use a normal toggleClass(), so I found a solution and I do an if condition to find if the overlay is already showed

everything works fine, but I have a problem, if the user double click on the li.dropdown, this solution doesn't work anymore :(

how can I hide the overlayer if the user double click on the li.dropdown?

this is my codepen > https://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/KrBOdB

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
    if (!$('.full-overlayer').hasClass('show')){
        $(".full-overlayer").toggleClass("show");
    }
});


$('.full-overlayer, .dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
    $('.full-overlayer').removeClass('show');
});
```

I am not sure if this was the best solution to approach to this task.

any suggestion or advice?

Comment: i suppose you may try to use .one() instead of .click()

Comment: Once check this solution, I think it's help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/ishimdar/y4fpgyg4/5/

Comment: thanks for this, but it doesn't work very well, if you click the first dropdown and then the second, you can see the the overlay is not shown anymore

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING CODEPEN** -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/grdgva]

```
$('li.dropdown').on('click',function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
        $(".full-overlayer").addClass("show");
    } else
    {
        $(".full-overlayer").removeClass("show");
    }
});


$('.full-overlayer, .dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
    $('.full-overlayer').removeClass('show');
});
```

Maybe it helps...

Comment: thanks for this, but it doesn't work very well. if you click (open the dropdown) and then you double click you will notice that doesn't work. try here https://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/rLAXKE

Comment: Modified the answer with the content of my last comment, if you want to consider my answer. Thankyou, hagd.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I found a solution that works.
I added another if condition to check if this has class "open"

```
  if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    $(".full-overlayer").removeClass("show");
  }
```

I am testing now, but it seems work, or at least I hope

here the codepen if somebody need for the future > https://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/kXjOAN